# Python: Recursively move/backup file folders older than x days. error 183

Tags: python, backup, move, errno

I'm writing a script to backup folders older then X days to another destination.
I keep getting an error 183 'Access is denied'

What do I do wrong?

```
import os
import time


xdays = 21
path = 'c:\\test'
new = 'c:\\test_test'
now = time.time()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for name in dirs:
    dirname = os.path.join(root, name)
    if os.stat(dirname).st_mtime < now - (xdays * 86400):
      os.rename(dirname, new)
  break
```

Comment: Will you please give full traceback ?

Comment: I want to search for folders older than 21 days and move them to given destination, once a week. If I replace `os.rename(dirname, new)` to `print(dirname)` I'm getting a nice list of folders that I need to move. `break` at the end causes that script stop search in first level, as I do not care what's inside each folder and how old the content is. With what I got, I run a script and it stops on first found folder with errno 183.